# Failed to use OnnxRuntime on Windows 7

Tags: .net-core, deep-learning, windows-7, onnx, onnxruntime

Here's an issue we are encountering when using OnnxRuntime on Windows 7. We have provided below the software environment of our machine for your reference.

**Software Environment**

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2022
- dotnet 6.0
- Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime 1.14.1 (distributed by NuGet)

While the project works on Windows 10, we have encountered an issue when attempting to move the release package to a Windows 7 machine. Specifically, the executable file is unable to load the `onnxruntime.dll`. The issue has been brought to our attention on GitHub, where we noticed the following comment: https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/5483

It was mentioned that the issue has been resolved in [#4636](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/pull/4636), however, we still have not been able to successfully launch the program on Windows 7. We hope that you could assist us in finding a solution.

We have tried:

- Copying the dll file from Windows 10 to the Windows 7 machine and attempting to register it
- Compiling the ORT in Windows 7. While the compilation was successful, its unit tests failed due to the `kernel32.dll`
- Using older versions of ORT

Comment: FWIW, .Net 6 no longer officially supports Windows 7 at all, and MS considers Windows 7 fully end of life. In fact, the thread you linked to is from 2020, _before Windows 7 was retired._ This is a BIG DEAL. It means Windows 7 no longer gets any updates... **not even critical security patches**. That makes it dangerous and irresponsible to continue using it.

Comment: Yes Joel but due to the hardware limit the project must run on Windows 7 machine. Thankfully the problem solved once we tried to compile the right version of ORT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved after my mailing to a key developer from Microsoft.

**Solution:** You just need to compile it yourself from source. The `onnxruntime.dll` in the Nuget package does not support Windows 7, and latest code starting from `1.15.0` does not support windows 7 **even when compiled from source**. So try to download the `1.14.1` code and compile `onnxruntime.dll` yourself.

Comment: For people who need it but can't compile it by themselves, can you share the file please ?

Comment: Hi Diego, I encountered the issue over half a year ago and therefore no longer have the compiled file. I suggest downloading the source code of the correct ORT version and following online guidance to compile it.